# Handle huge amount of data using Java EE

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, database, oracle

We have a Java EE application that support Oracle, MySQL and SQL Server vendors.
we are using a view model to view the fetched data from DB, also using pagination in the DAO model, and that's working good so far, but now we are working with millions of records like 10 millions, that cause to us a big problem since our application performance issues become very bad. After some investigations we had make we found that the order by in the query cause a big slowness in the DB level, but we still have to use it.

The question is : is there any technique to work with this amount of data with a good performance (response time and memory issues) ?

Comment: There are lots of them and most will not work for your situation. This is way outside the bounds of SO. I suggest http://programmers.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ORDER BY` clause frequently you should create an **index** on field your are ordering by. It would dramatically increase ordering performance (but of course will slightly slow down insertion).

Comment: Hi Michal Borek, thanks for your answers.
we have a 25 - 30 column in average with at least 32 foreign key (sub tables), is it harm to perform indexing for all these columns.

Comment: 32 foreign keys and a 10 million row table, sounds like some refactoring may help too

Comment: @JUBA I think you must balance number of indexes, to put them where you are ordering the most often. You can also combine it with caching, because I guess some of queries are invoked more often that the other ones.